# Java Exception as checked Exception but not required to be thrown in trycatch

Tags: java, exception

I have this snippet.

```
public final class StackOverflow{
   class MyException extends Throwable{
   }
   private void a(){
       try{
       }catch(MyException | Exception e){
       }
   }
}
exception StackOverflow.MyException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
```

I know that Exception is extending Throwable as well and also is a checked exception also MyException is extending Throwable which mades also a checked exception!

My question is why Exception is not required to be thrown in the try catch but MyException is? I think that both are checked exception so which is the difference??

Sorry if the question is simple.

Comment: Making your exception extend `Exception` would resolve this.

Comment: This is because ```RuntimeException``` (extends Exception) is the root class for all unchecked exceptions, hence the compiler does not mock up on this one. The ```catch Exception``` would thus also match all unchecked exceptions. ```MyException``` on the other hand is explicitly a checked exception, because you inherit the root ```Throwable``` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is explained in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3) (emphasis in bold):

> It is a compile-time error if a `catch` clause *can catch* checked exception class E1 and it is not the case that the `try` block corresponding to the `catch` clause *can throw* a checked exception class that is a subclass or superclass of E1, **unless E1 is `Exception` or a superclass of `Exception`.**

I guess the rationale behind this is that: `MyException` is indeed a checked exception. However, unchecked exceptions also extend `Exception` (transitive inheritance from `RuntimeException`), so having a `catch` include the `Exception` class is excluded from the exception analysis done by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Exception extends from `RuntimeException` will considered as uncheched exception, so it's ok:

```
class MyException extends RuntimeException { }

try {
    ...
} catch (MyException e) {

}
```

Your exception extends from `Throwable`, so it is cheched exception. Since the compiler noticed that it is never thrown, so the compile fails.